# Find related rows that have "nothing in between them"

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id INT(10) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  from DATE(10) NOT NULL,
  before DATE(10) NULL,
  reference_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
)
```

So there are rows that reference another table (with `reference_id`). Those references have a date range (`from`/`before`) in which they are applicable. **For each `reference_id`** there may be many entries which usually have no gaps:

```
id | from       | before     | reference_id
-------------------------------------------
1  | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-05 | 5
5  | 2019-03-05 | 2019-03-09 | 5
8  | 2019-03-09 | NULL       | 5
```

(There might be entries for other `reference_id`s between them.) An entry begins where the previous ended. Now I want to find all entries that have a gap between them, where the `from` is later than the `before` of the preceding. For example (change in row `2`, column `from`):

```
id | from       | before     | reference_id
-------------------------------------------
1  | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-05 | 5
5  | 2019-03-06 | 2019-03-09 | 5
8  | 2019-03-09 | NULL       | 5
```

Row 2's `from` is one day later than row 1's `before`, that's a gap. The problem: for rows 3 and 1 the same is true, but they should not be considered as result because they have another row between them.

What I came up with is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable mt1
INNER JOIN mytable mt2 ON mt1.reference_id = mt2.reference_id AND mt1.id != mt2.id
WHERE mt1.before IS NOT NULL
  AND mt1.from < mt2.from
  AND DATE_ADD(mt1.before, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = mt2.from
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM mytable mt3 WHERE mt3.id BETWEEN mt1.id AND mt2.id)
```

However, this (the `EXISTS`) is incredibly slow. Is there a better way to do this?

[edit]The query just finished and I didn't get any results although I'm definitly expecting some. So it's not only slow but also incorrect.[/edit]

---

Execution plan:

```
1,PRIMARY,mt1,ALL,"mytable_48d78c2b,mytable_261384ee,mytable_849034da",,,,3313021,Using where
1,PRIMARY,mt2,ref,"mytable_48d78c2b,mytable_849034da",mytable_849034da,4,db.mt1.reference_id,1,Using index condition; Using where
2,DEPENDENT SUBQUERY,mt3,index,PRIMARY,mytable_48d78c2b,3,,3313021,Using where; Using index
```

Comment: Any explain/execution plan (or similar)?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB

Comment: I added the execution plan

Comment: THB, I didn't think this would be an issue of setting an index here and there or doing engine specific stuff, rather me doing it plain wrong or naive or not how a SQL magician would do it.

Comment: Could there be overlap as well as gaps? for instance `before` of row 2 which would be `2019-03-10` with unchanged row 3?

Comment: Well, if it makes the query simpler I wouldn't mind finding overlaps as well. But it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note that `from` is a very bad choice for a column name as it is a reserved keyword. But well, it is valid, so there we go.)

Assuming no overlap, you can use the [lag](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lag/) function to look up the `before` of the previous row: `lag(before, 1) over (partition by reference_id order by before) as previous_before`. From there on, if it easy to check if there is a gap, if `from > previous_before`

```
select
    `from`, before, `reference_id`
  , `from` > lag(before, 1) over (partition by reference_id order by before) as has_gap
from mytable
```

What the `lag` does is to find the `before` value of the previous row, previous being determined by the `order by` clause of the window function. If `from` and before are identical, there is no gap.

This query gives you row with a gap before them, you can use the [lead](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lead/) function in the same way to get rows with a gap after them.

Note that MariaDB has window functions since 10.2.2 only.

Comment: Thanks so much already. However, a "previous" row should be one with the same `reference_id`. Maybe I could solve that with `order by reference_id` first. Apart from that I don't have MariaDB 10.2. Even the most recent Ubuntu is only on 10.1. If there's no other solution I'll try do get that version somehow.

Comment: @Tim-Erwin I forgot about the same `reference_id`, I fixed the query (by adding the `partition by` clause). If you have enough control on your server, you can just add the relevant MariaDB repo and use a newer version: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=nluug&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=cosmic--ubuntu_cosmic&version=10.3 The window functions are well worth the update (and there are new things with virtual columns as well which are very interesting).

Comment: thanks for the query. I was able to update to 10.3. I had to wrap the query in another SELECT so I only get those that have a gap, works like a charm!